# Having problems using curl post a json object from a variable in bash

Tags: json, bash, curl

So I'm writing a script that needs to create a json object, and post it with curl.

This is working:

curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{ "_type": "_test", "_device": "123.123.123.123", "_system": "web-services", "result": "success", "_time": "123", "error": "" }' $data_pipeline

$data_pipeline contains the URL for the post request

if $json_string contains the string including single quotes:
'{ "_type": "_test", "_device": "123.123.123.123", "_system": "web-services", "result": "success", "_time": "123", "error": "" }'

This should work but it doesn't:

curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data $json_string $data_pipeline

First I was creating the $json_object without the single quotes, and tried to add them on the command line for CURL.  If I don't escape the single quotes, $json_string is sent as a literal, instead of expanding the variable.  I escaped the single quotes, and it did not help, I even tried a double escape in case that was needed, and still it is not working.  It only works if I put the entire json string by hand, but not if I put it in a variable.  How can I fix this?  The json is dynamically created by the script, using jq, and the json is valid as I can successfully run the post by hand, I just need it to work with a variable.  It won't work without the single quotes, but the single quotes don't work when I use a variable to hold the json, it doesn't matter if I put the single quotes in the variable, or try to do it outside of the variable...  How do I fix this?

The json object is built with this code:

```
json_string=\'$( jq -n \
              --arg _type "$_type" \
              --arg _device "$_device" \
              --arg _system "$_system" \
              --arg result "$result" \
              --arg _time "$_time" \
              --arg error "$error" \
              '{_type: $_type, _device: $_device, _system: $_system, result: $result, _time: $_time, error: $error}' )\'
```

Originally I was creating the json_string without the ' but I added that in attempt to get the single quotes wrapped around the json.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wrapping the json in literal single quotes? That's invalid json. You should also quote `"$json_string"`

Comment: because that is required for curl.  The json without single quotes does not go through,  curl cannot understand the command line then.  When I include the single quites, the json works.  Examples of posting json with curl also show the single quotes in use.  I'm just trying to capture the json in a string so that my script can use it cleanly.  The raw json in single quotes works fine in my script, but then I can't use the jq tool to pre-process the json.  I've tried to put the jq command on the curl command line but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @HomerTX Did you try jordanm's suggestion? It should work (and in general, you should almost always put double-quotes around shell variable references). It'll work because quotes (and escapes and things like that) in shell variables aren't treated the same as quotes that're actually part of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

_type="hello"

# let's have some fun
_device="single'quote"
_system='double"quote'
error='multi
line'

encode()
{
    printf "%s" "$1" | sed 's/"/%22/' | tr '\n' ' '
}

# you don't need encode() if your strings are not json-offensive
json_string="{
    _type: \"$_type\"
    _device: \"$_device\"
    _system: \"$(encode "$_system")\"
    error: \"$(encode "$error")\"
}"
set -x
curl \
    -X POST \
    -d "$json_string" \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    http://httpbin.org/anything
```

Output:

```
+ curl -X POST -d '{
    _type: "hello"
    _device: "single'\''quote"
    _system: "double%22quote"
    error: "multi line"
}' -H 'content-type: application/json' http://httpbin.org/anything
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\n\t_type: \"hello\"\n\t_device: \"single'quote\"\n\t_system: \"double%22quote\"\n\terror: \"multi line\"\n}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "92", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.58.0", 
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "POST", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```